# bizarre copy of array in list assignment at c:perl64/lib/carp.pm line 229

Tags: perl

i wrote this code in windows active Perl  to read Excel-XML file and while 
 executing the same code some times its giving me error as mentioned above 
 and when i keep on running it.  sometime time it will run and again raise 
 same error.

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;


    use Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML;
    my $workbook =  Spreadsheet::Reader::ExcelXML->new( file=>'perl.pl', group_return_type => 'value',);

    if ( !$workbook->file_opened ) {
            die $workbook->error(), ".\n";
    }

    my  $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet( 'Sheet5' );                                      

    my $value;
    while( !$value or $value ne 'EOF' ){
            $value = $worksheet->fetchrow_arrayref;
            my @a=@{$value};
            Function(@a);
    }

    sub Function {
            my @rows =@_;
            print "@rows\n";
    }
```

Comment: That error points to a bug in an XS module. (It's extremely unlikely, but it could also be a bug in Perl itself.)

Comment: Are you really passing `perl.pl` as the path to the spreadsheet?

Comment: no sir actual path is C:\Users\adm\OneDrive\filename.xlsm

Comment: Still not a spreadsheet!

Comment: C;\Users\adm\onedrive\filename.xlsm

Comment: There are bug reports on very similar behavior, related to `Carp` hooking into the debugger I believe. I've seen a comment that it disappeared in v5.16.  What version of Perl are you running?

Comment: I have installed active perl version perl 5.24.2 in windows

Comment: can anyone help me its urgent!!!!!

Comment: I guess it is in the line `die $workbook->error(), ".\n";` where  $workbook->error() in list-context returns something weird. replace the , with a . and see if this helps

Comment: i changed but not working.

Comment: is it solvable bug? or i have change my code